# Bash: How to convert a string that is in MONDDHR:MI to a date in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the date value stored as a string in a file in MONDDHR:MI format. I need to convert that into a date value so that I can perform some date operations on it. I tried to convert the value but I am getting invalid date error as mentioned below

```
date -d "Oct3108:31"
date: invalid date `Oct3108:31'
```

Is it possible to convert this string to a date value?

Comment: This is probably not what you want but you can do that conversion using Python's [```time```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module: ```time.asctime(time.strptime('Oct3108:31', '%b%d%H:%M'))``` resulting in ```Wed Oct 31 08:31:00 1900```.

Comment: Is this linux specific? From the man page: `-d dst  Set the kernel's value for daylight saving time.  If dst is non-zero, future calls to gettimeofday(2) will return a non-zero for tz_dsttime.` . I suspect that is not what you expect for `-d`

Comment: Anything will be specific to the implementation of `date`. The POSIX standard for `date` doesn't say anything about parsing an argument in anything other than `mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]` format.

Comment: @WilliamPursell GNU date uses `-d` to specify an argument in a fairly arbitrary (but poorly documented) fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hacky (understatement), but you could try:

```
date -d "$(echo "Oct3108:31" | sed -e 's/\(.....\)/\1 /')"
```

and just insert a space between the day and the hour.